# after update state getting data again and again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

> I want to fetch data from an API and display data in Component
> but after update state also getting previous values
> here is [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-leaf-8mc8o?file=/src/options.js:115-753)

```
export const Options = () => {
      const [region, setRegion] = useState(null);
    
      const selectRegionHandler = (e) => {
        let select = e.target.value;
        if (select !== "Select Region") {
          console.log(select);
          axios(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/${select}`).then((res) =>
            setRegion(res.data)
          );
        }
      };
    
      if (region !== null) {
        return <Region data={region} />;
      }
    
      return (
        <select onChange={selectRegionHandler}>
          <option>Select Region</option>
          <option>Asia</option>
          <option>Africa</option>
          <option>Europe</option>
        </select>
      );
    };
```

> In Region Component I'm passing data

Comment: I have added the answer. Please try and let me know if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**region.js**: You need to remove option from region.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Options } from "./options";
export const Region = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="regionData">
        <div className="listData">
          {data.map((data) => (
            <li key={data.name}>{data.name},</li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**option.js:** Wrap the api call in useEffect and dependency should be option. Just set the option state when combo value is changed that will trigger the api call to pull the region collection.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Region } from "./region";

export const Options = () => {
  const [region, setRegion] = useState(null);
  const [option, setOption] = useState("Select Region");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (option !== "Select Region") {
      console.log(option);
      axios(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/region/${option}`).then((res) =>
        setRegion(res.data)
      );
    }
  }, [option]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setOption(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={handleChange}>
        <option>Select Region</option>
        <option>Asia</option>
        <option>Africa</option>
        <option>Europe</option>
      </select>
      {region && <Region data={region} />}
    </>
  );
};
```